# Set a linearLayout at top while scrolling which is inside of scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-scrollview

I have a xml file like-

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout>
            <ImageView />
            <----more components--->
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llSomeLayout">
            <----components---> 
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

What I want is-> When linearLayout with id @+id/llSomeLayout from above reaches at top, want to stop that layout from going out of view or want show similar view/layout at top when that goes out of view.
What mechanism should I follow to achieve that?

Comment: I got answer but can I come to know please why I got down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyScrollViewItems

```
dependencies {
   compile 'se.emilsjolander:StickyScrollViewItems:x.x.x'
}
```

Then

```
<StickyScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/sticky_scroll"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!-- other children -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSomeLayout"
        android:layout_height="300dp" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:tag="sticky"/>

    <!-- other children -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: how can make the sticky view become horizontal scrollable? cos it can't scroll horizontal after I added te sticky scroll view. (Before this its horizontal scrollable)